# Why is $E[AA^T]$ not necessarily invertible if $A$ is a high-dimensional vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I'm reading a [blog entry](http://francisbach.com/the-sum-of-a-geometric-series-is-all-you-need/) and there it says

> We assume that the feature vector $\phi(x)$ is high-dimensional, so
>   that the moment matrix $H=E[\phi(x)\phi(x)^{T}]$ cannot be assumed to
>   be invertible.

I don't see why this claim makes any sense and does anyone here understand why this is the case? On a side note, I can't stand when authors don't justify these claims.

Comment: What is $E$?${}$

Comment: $E$ is an expectation.

Comment: Other folks have pointed out why $AA^\top$ won't have an inverse. I don't think it's true in general that the dimension of $\phi(x)$ will be related to whether $H$ has an inverse or not (at least, not in the absence of other assumptions), but it is true that the **empirical** version of $H$, $\widehat H = N^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^N \phi(x_i) \phi(x_i)^\top$ will have rank at most $N$, so that if the dimension of $\phi(x)$ exceeds $N$ then $\widehat H$ will not have an inverse.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen : You know how to misunderstand a question. See my comments under two of the answers below.

Comment: I have done some fumbling and fixed the link to the blog post in your question which should hopefully help others better understand the context of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a random column vector $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}$ is constrained to lie within a $k$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^{n\times1}$ with $k<n,$ then the expected value $\operatorname E(A A^\top)$ will have columns within that subspace, so its rank cannot exceed $k.$

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. It doesn't seem like this is stated with justification in textbooks, or at least not the ones I use.

Comment: The standard proof here is to consider the quadratic form for any $\mathbf v \neq \mathbf 0$ which is: $\mathbf v^T \operatorname E(A A^\top) \mathbf v  = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i v_j E[A_i A_j] =  E[\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n v_i v_j A_i A_j] = E[(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i A_i)^2]\geq 0$   where inequality is strict unless there is a non-trivial linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i A_i = 0$ (equivalently they are constrained to live in a space with dimension $\lt n$).  This is essentially the same technique as used when proving whether a Gram matrix is nonsingular.

Comment: Michael, I don't understand the philosophy of your writing. The OP (who besides did not know that if $V$ is a vector, then, in general, $rank(VV^T)=1$!!) did not write that $ V $ varies in a subspace of dimension $k<n$. In fact, if $k=n$ then $E(VV^T)$ is invertible for any standard law. For example, if $n=10$ and the entries of $V$ are uniform random integers in $(-100,100)$, then $det(E(VV^T))\approx 1.5\times 10^{35}$. On the other hand, whether $n$ is large or not , doesn't change the problem.

Comment: Where did it seem like I didn’t know rank VV^t was 1? I’m genuinely wondering. Also there is no reason to put down someone if he DIDN’T know that.

Comment: My point was the same as Michael’s...analyzing E(XX^t) is not the same as XX^t...

Comment: To the OP. I write that you are not an eagle for the two following reasons. i) Your first comment (18h29) to the Fimpellizieri's post. ii) The fact that you gave the green chevron to Michael, whereas he answered only very partially to your question; in particular, he only dealt with the very straightforward case. The case $k=n$ is much more interesting (do you understand that, my friend ?).

Comment: No that’s the case I had in mind! And yeah, k=n is more interesting. I’m not sure what an eagle means here...?

Comment: And then doesn’t that mean the blog post claim isn’t valid now when k=n...? Sorry I’m better at stats than I am at math...

Comment: Yes you are right. The considered result is not valid when $k=n$, that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=[v_1,\cdots,v_n]^T$ be a random vector $V\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Assume that the $(v_i)_i$ are independent and $v_i$ follows a law with mean $m_i$and standard deviation $\sigma_i$.

Consider $VV^T=[v_iv_j]_{i,j}$, a random symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix.

Then $E(VV^T)=[E(v_iv_j)]$ is a symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix where, if $i\not=j$,

then $E(v_iv_j)=m_im_j$ and $E(v_i^2)=\sigma_i^2+m_i^2$. Remark that $M=[m_im_j]$ is a symmetric$\geq 0$ matrix.

Finally $E(VV^T)=M+diag(\sigma_i^2)$. If, for every $i$, $\sigma_i>0$ (that is $v_i$ is not constant), then $E(VV^T)$ is symmetric $>0$  and, in particular, invertible.

EDIT. There can be a problem when $n$ is large and the $\sigma_i/m_i$ are small.

For example, assume that the data $(v_i)$ are known with $7$ significant digits, $n=1000,m_i=1,\sigma_i^2=10^{-3}$.

Then the condition number of $E(VV^T)$ is $2\times 10^7$ and we can't calculate its inverse.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $u, v\in\Bbb R^n$, with $M = vv^T$ we have

$$Mu = vv^Tu = \langle v, u\rangle v$$

In other words, $Mu$ is always a multiple of $v$.
This means the image of $M$ has dimension $1$. It follows that whenever $n\geqslant 2$, we necessarily have that $vv^T$ fails to be invertible.

Comment: This looks like something which should have been included in that original blog post too. I don't see how this would have been obvious.

Comment: This is fairly standard. I just find it weird to speak of 'high dimensionality'. These kinds of matrices are studied usually in the context of projection matrices, when $v$ has norm $1$. See [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Formulas).

Comment: But the question is about the expected value, which is an average of rank-1 matrices. That typically has an average higher than 1.

Comment: I've down-voted this for the reason explained in my comment above.

Comment: Correction: I meant "That typically has an RANK higher than 1. "